# Working through Math 55 problem sets as self-study

Tags: soft-question, big-list

I am not a professional mathematician, but have learnt Engineering Mathematics in college and worked through parts of maths textbooks myself. The latter include the first few chapters of include Real Analysis (Hijab), Topology (Munkres), Algebra (Artin), Complex Analysis (Ahlfors) and Differential Geometry (Pressley, Kreyszig).  I would like to work through the problem sets of the Harvard Maths 55 course for self-study.

*Would you have any tips for this, considering I'll be doing all this alone and without an instructor and classmates?*

I'll be happy to provide any more relevant information.

Comment: I don't know what you're looking for.  As someone who never really went to class, I don't see any problem with that.  Just try your best to get a hold of the solutions so you can check your methodology.

Comment: If you were capable of doing the first few chapters of all those books, why don't you continue them?

Comment: I took Math 55 at Harvard! But that was in 1968, it might have changed a little bit since then....

Comment: Dear Ganesh: my impression is that what you have already studied is more than what Math 55 covers today (linear algebra, introductory abstract algebra, real analysis, a little complex analysis). I understand the curriculum was standardized a few years back, and consequently the older classes were sometimes more advanced.

Comment: @Akhil, Thanks for the info. Though I've learnt parts of the material, I want to do the ultra-hard problem sets.